# .htaccess only apply to it's own directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want my domains to be a bit tidier by removing extensions in the URL. Here are two examples.

Before: `domain.ext/index.php`

After: `domain.ext/index/`

This is what I've gathered from another (inactive) question here:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]
```

Right now I'm developing in another directory from my root, and it's replacing the following URL:

```
domain.ext/versionx/search.php
```

with:

```
domain.ext/search.php
```

which of course doesn't exist right now. Is there a way to modify this code so that it will only affect the files in it's own directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

If it doesn't work for some reason provide details like for which url it doesn't work and what is location of your .htaccess and if there are other rules also.